# Suppress axis in lattice plot

Tags: r, lattice, r-caret, trellis

I am using caret's `featurePlot` function to create a lattice plot. The X and Y axes show up in the diagonal boxes (see picture).  I want to suppress these axes-- both the tickmarks and labels.

---

[image]

---

Thought I could set scales$draw to NULL, but that did not work. Here is what I tried:

```
trellisDefaultSettings = trellis.par.get()
trellis.par.set(theme=transparentTheme(trans = .4),
                scales$draw=FALSE,
                warn=FALSE)

featurePlot(x = features[, -1 * ncol(features)],
            y = features$SpeciesName,
            plot = "pairs",
            auto.key = list(columns = 5))
```

Comment: Use `pscales=FALSE`: see `?panel.pairs` for details

Comment: @user20650: The SO powers that be would rather an answer be submitted as an answer. It lets questions get marked as answered.

Comment: Well, I thought it was creditworthy. Filled a gap in my knowledge.

Comment: Thanks @42- ; I do need to stop being so lazy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the argument `pscales`.

Example

```
library(caret)

featurePlot(x = iris[, -1 * ncol(iris)],
            y = iris$Species,
            plot = "pairs",
            auto.key = list(columns = 3),
            pscales=FALSE)
```

From looking at the code for `featurePlot`, you can see it calls `lattice::splom` for the `pairs` plot. The help page for this function describes which argument to use (see also `?panel.pairs`)